# React: Using error boundries to highligh broken components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm using React 16.3 which has support for error boundaries, via `ComponentDidCatch()` function overrides. I'm using typescript as well.

For ease of future debugging I want to somehow catch any errors/exceptions at the component level in order to highlight (draw yellow square) in the UI indicating the possition of broken component.

How could I do this without having to explicitly declare error boundary around every single component that I use?

Perhaps its possible to wrap them during build time? I also presume error boundary would need to somehow get the props from broken component in order to know where to draw yellow square. How could I accomplish that?

I'm quite new to React so thanks in advance.

Comment: I also probably should note that I'm also using couple custom basic components (Text/View/Image) which do not inherit from React components.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you want to use error boundary then use it inside the dom render.

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {ErrorBoundary} from 'your-path';

    ReactDOM.render(
        <ErrorBoundary>
           //Router or other stuff
        </ErrorBoundary>,
        document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
    );
```

create `ErrorBoundary` component like this.

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface IErrorBoundaryState {
    isError: boolean;
    error: React.ErrorInfo;
}

export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<{}, IErrorBoundaryState> {

    this.state = {isError: false, error: null};

    componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: React.ErrorInfo): void {
        this.setState({ isError: true, error: errorInfo });
    }

    render(): any {
        if (this.state.isError) {
            return <div>{this.state.error.componentStack}</div>;
        }

        return this.props.children;
    }
}
```